# Windows 7 and ScreenShot.cpp GDI+ PNG problemo

Tags: c++, bitmap, png, gdi+, screenshot

was using XP without issue for a long time. switched to 7 and trying to capture screenshots with my previously functioning code no longer works. simple concept and relatively generic code...just find the window that i call and save it as a .png. any ideas what might make this bad boy run again? can't debug with my current setup, but it makes it all the way and spits out the error message after bmp->save(...) ...couldn't save image file. edit: also a file does get created/saved, but it is blank and not written to. perhaps the bitmap encoding or GDI is screwed up?

```
bool CScreenShot::Snap(CString wintitle, CString file, CString& ermsg)
{
    ermsg = ""; // no error message

    // create screen shot bitmap
    EnumWinProcStruct prm = {0, (LPSTR)(LPCTSTR)wintitle, 0};

    // Find the descriptor of the window with the caption wintitle
    EnumDesktopWindows(0, EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)&prm);
    if(!prm.hwnd)
    {
        ermsg.Format("couldn't find window \"%s\"", wintitle);
        return false;
    }

    // Make the window the topmost window
    SetWindowPos(prm.hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
    Sleep(300);

    // Get device context for the top-level window and client rect
    HDC hDC = GetDC(prm.hwnd);
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(prm.hwnd, &rc);

    HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

    // Set the size and color depth for the screen shot image
    BITMAPINFO bmpInfo;
    memset(&bmpInfo, 0, sizeof(bmpInfo));
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmpInfo.bmiHeader);
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = rc.right - rc.left;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = rc.bottom - rc.top;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth * bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight * 3;

    // Create memory buffer and perform a bit-block transfer of the color data from the window to the memory
    LPVOID  addr;
    HBITMAP memBM   = CreateDIBSection(memDC, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &addr, 0, 0);

    HGDIOBJ stdBM   = SelectObject(memDC, memBM);
    BOOL    OK      = BitBlt(memDC, 0, 0, bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth, bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, hDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    ReleaseDC(prm.hwnd, hDC);

    SetWindowPos(prm.hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);

    // Initialize GDI+.
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;
    if(GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL) != Ok)
    {
        ermsg.Format("couldn't start GDI+");
        return false;
    }

    // Create a Bitmap object for work with images defined by pixel data from the GDI HBitmap and the GDI HPalette.
    Bitmap* bmp = ::new Bitmap(memBM, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    SelectObject(memDC, stdBM);
    DeleteObject(memBM);
    DeleteDC(memDC);

    // Find the encoder for "image/png" mime type
    CLSID encoderClsid;
    EncoderParameters encoderParameters;

    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &encoderClsid);

    encoderParameters.Count = 0;

    // Convert file name to Unicode (wide-char) string.
    WCHAR   fn[_MAX_PATH];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_THREAD_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED, file, file.GetLength() + 1, fn, _MAX_PATH);
    // Save the screen shot into the specified file using image encoder with the mime style "image/png"
    if(bmp->Save(fn, &encoderClsid, &encoderParameters) != Ok)
    {
        ermsg.Format("couldn't save image file \"%s\"", file);
        return false;
    }

    ::delete bmp;
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

win7 won't accept encoderParameters.Count == 0 for some reason. Set that == 1 and you should be all set.

you probably could also just remove that parameter from Save() (overloaded)

Comment: i should add that this solves the issue above...but a new issue associated with win7 presents itself with this code: opengl app screenshot will only get the frame and not the child window.

Answer (score 1):

The error message implies that you're trying to save the file to a folder that you don't have permission to write to. Many folders such as Program Files are now protected. Since you didn't include the path in your sample code I'm unable to determine if this is the actual problem.

**Edit:** Another possibility is that the Bitmap is improperly constructed which causes the Save to fail. The second parameter to the constructor is supposed to be a handle to a palette, I think DIB_RGB_COLORS would be invalid here and you should use NULL. Also there are a couple of caveats noted in the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536314(v=vs.85).aspx) and perhaps the different OS versions react differently when you break the rules:

> You are responsible for deleting the GDI bitmap and the GDI palette. However, you should not delete the GDI bitmap or the GDI palette until after the GDI+ Bitmap::Bitmap object is deleted or goes out of scope.
>
> Do not pass to the GDI+ Bitmap::Bitmap constructor a GDI bitmap or a GDI palette that is currently (or was previously) selected into a device context.

Comment: appreciated, but i'm just saving to a generic folder on the C: drive that my program actually creates for me prior to taking the screenshot (to store the screenshot, as well as logs, to).....so i definitely have permission...

Comment: If your app is un-elevated it might not have permission to create the folder. Try creating the folder by hand and see if it works after that. Alternatively, try creating the folder under AppData (per user storage.)

Comment: all elevated...there just seems to be a difference between XP and win7 somewhere. a file does get created with the correct name in the correct folder, but the file is 0kb and content is not filled.